# Checking protocol conformance when using factory methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-protocol

I have recently been learning how to use protocols in Objective-C (using Apple's official guide) and I've been having trouble understanding what seems to me to be an inconsistency. In the documentation it is stated that -

> By specifying the required protocol conformance on the property, you’ll get a compiler warning if you attempt to set the property to an object that doesn’t conform to the protocol, even though the basic property class type is generic.

So I test this out by creating a protocol called 'XYZFakeProtocol' and a class called 'XYZPerson' that does not conform to this protocol. I then attempt to initialise a generic class variable which is expected to conform to XYZFakeProtocol as follows -

```
id <XYZFakeProtocol> speakingPerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
```

As expected, XCode flags up the error -

> Initializing '__strong id`<`XYZFakeProtocol>' with an expression of incompatible type 'XYZPerson *'

However, when I do the same thing but instead use a factory method as opposed to manually allocating and initialising an instance, the error does not come up. The code I used, with the factory method being 'person:' -

```
id <XYZFakeProtocol> speakingPerson = [XYZPerson person];
```

No error is flagged, and, especially problematically, no compiler error also appears when I call a method specified in the protocol, even when that method is not actually in the non-conforming class - this causes my program to crash.

So is this a problem with Xcode, or is this the expected and correct outcome of using a factory method, and, if so, could the reasoning behind this be explained to me so that I can understand how best to avoid it when I'm coding a real application?

For reference, Xcode correctly flags an error that the class does not conform to the protocol if I create an XYZPerson object and assign it to an XYZPerson variable, and then assign that variable to the generic type variable, regardless of whether the instance was created using a factory method or initialised manually -

```
XYZPerson *helloPerson = [XYZPerson person];
XYZPerson *helloPerson2 = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
id <XYZFakeProtocol> speakingPerson = helloPerson;
speakingPerson = helloPerson2;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the return type for the `person` class method on `XYZPerson`?

Comment: you need to return `instancetype` not `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to assume you've declared as:

```
+ (id)person;
```

Change that to:

```
+ (instancetype)person;
```

`id` represents any type so the compiler doesn't know whether the object returned will implement the protocol or not. `instancetype` means an instance of that type so the compiler does know.

`instancetype` is a relatively new addition and hence the compiler is happy to adduce it for `init` methods. It's however not willing to do so for factory methods.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Annoying that it was such a simple error, but good that I've got the importance of the factory method return type in my head now - I guess I was confusing it with the initialiser method return type.

Comment: @ivoisebelongtous Your various `init` methods should also return `instancetype` instead of `id`.

Comment: Noted. It appears the Apple guide I was following is a bit outdated.

Comment: @ivoisebelongtous Using `instancetype` is relatively new. Apple is beginning to migrate its use to its own code.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how your XYZPerson class is defined. If `person` returns `id`, then the type checker will treat it as being compatible with any object type. If `person` returns `instancetype`, you'll get the error about protocol conformance.